# How can I simplify this code for graphic2d?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, graphics2d

There has to be an easier way to do this to make blades of grass! Please help!
Maybe a loop of some sort or an Array. The blades of grass as you can tell alternate per row of arcs but writing them all out is too time consuming.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyPanel extends JPanel

{public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  { Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

    //Background
    Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    Color skyBlue = new Color(135,206,235);
    g2.setColor(skyBlue);
    g2.fill (background);

    //Grass
    Rectangle grass = new Rectangle(0,525,getWidth(),100);
    Color lawnGreen = new Color(124,252,0);
    g2.setColor(lawnGreen);
    g2.fill(grass);

    Arc2D.Double blade1 = new Arc2D.Double(10,500,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade2 = new Arc2D.Double(20,500,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade3 = new Arc2D.Double(30,500,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade4 = new Arc2D.Double(40,500,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade5 = new Arc2D.Double(50,500,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade6 = new Arc2D.Double(5,510,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN); 
    Arc2D.Double blade7 = new Arc2D.Double(15,510,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade8 = new Arc2D.Double(25,510,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade9 = new Arc2D.Double(35,510,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade10 = new Arc2D.Double(45,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade11 = new Arc2D.Double(10,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade12 = new Arc2D.Double(20,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN); 
    Arc2D.Double blade13 = new Arc2D.Double(30,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade14 = new Arc2D.Double(40,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);
    Arc2D.Double blade15 = new Arc2D.Double(50,520,10,35,105,180,Arc2D.OPEN);


    Color yellowGreen = new Color(107,142,35);
    g2.setColor(yellowGreen);
    g2.fill(blade1);
    g2.fill(blade2);
    g2.fill(blade3);
    g2.fill(blade4);
    g2.fill(blade5);
    g2.fill(blade6);
    g2.fill(blade7);
    g2.fill(blade8);
    g2.fill(blade9);
    g2.fill(blade10);
    g2.fill(blade11);
    g2.fill(blade12);
    g2.fill(blade13);
    g2.fill(blade14);
    g2.fill(blade15);

    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(60,100,25,25);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(circle);
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(150,100,20,80);
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(box);

    Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(10,10,150,150);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g2.draw(line);
 }
}
```

Comment: perhaps this belongs to [CodeReview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For one, **Don't** create your objects in the `paintComponent` method. Secondly, you're forgetting to call `super.paintComponent`.

Comment: You could also use a `List<Arc2D>` created _outside_ of the `paintComponent` method an just loop through it to paint them.

Comment: ok How can I not  draw my objects on paintComponent if I have to color and fill them with g2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should attempt to reduce the amount of short-lived objects you are creating in your paint method (IMHO).

Start by creating a `List` of `Shape`, which you can add the individual blades to

```
 private List<Shape> blades;
```

Fill this with the individual blades...

```
public MyPanel() {
    blades = new ArrayList<>(25);
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(10, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(20, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(30, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(40, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(50, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(5, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(15, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(25, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(35, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(45, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(10, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(20, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(30, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(40, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(50, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
```

Then simply iterate the list in the `paintComponent` method...

```
Color yellowGreen = new Color(107, 142, 35);
g2.setColor(yellowGreen);
for (Shape blade : blades) {
    g2.draw(blade);
}
```

Now, another option might be to create a `BufferedImage` and paint the "static" elements to it and simply paint the image when `paintComponent` is called.

Also, you must call `super.paintComponent` before you do any of your custom painting, otherwise you will end with weird paint artifacts.

You can further reduce it by doing something like...

```
blades = new ArrayList<>(25);
for (int x = 10; x < 50; x += 10) {
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
for (int x = 5; x < 45; x += 10) {
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
for (int x = 10; x < 50; x += 10) {
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
```

Or even...

```
for (int x = 10; x < 200; x += 10) {
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x - 5, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
```